# Return Blank If Formula Returns a Value Containing "@"

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm Using this Equation

> =IF(ISBLANK(A2),"",PROPER(LEFT(A2,FIND(".",A2)-1)))

To return the First name of an Email address however if an email is in johnj@test.com format and not john.johnson@test.com it returns johnj@test.

I want the cell to return blank if it returns a value containing the "@" Symbol.

Comment: Another way to think about this would be to test if the position of the `.` is less than the position of the `@`.

Comment: In an outer call check for the location of the @ and return that. Then on the inner, do an If check for a "."; if the "." is located, return the first part (LEFT(A2,FIND(".",A2)-1), otherwise return the @ Find (LEFT(A2,FIND("@",A2)-1). It's going to be nested IFs, and a bit long, but viable.

Comment: Can you Explain this @BigBen?

Answer (score 0):

Another way to think about this is to test the position of the found `.` against the position of the found `@`. If there's no period before the `@`, then just return a blank string.

You can easily add this check within your current formula:

```
=IF(OR(ISBLANK(A2),FIND(".",A2)>FIND("@",A2)),"",PROPER(LEFT(A2,FIND(".",A2)-1)))
```

[image]

**EDIT:**

You may want something like this to handle blank cells:

```
=IFERROR(IF(FIND(".",A2)>FIND("@",A2),"",PROPER(LEFT(A2,FIND(".",A2)-1))),"")
```

Comment: This works, however if A3 is blank it shoots back an error #VALUE! can I add the if A# is blank return blank back on to it?

Comment: That Worked Perfectly I was also using this Equation 

=IF(ISBLANK(A2),"",PROPER(LEFT(RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-FIND(".",A2)),FIND("@",RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-FIND(".",A2)))-1)))

To pull the last name, how would I go about applying what you did to this formula? I tried but I got an error that said "Too Few Arguments"

This is What I tried:

=IFERROR(IF(FIND(".",A2)>FIND("@",A2),"",PROPER(LEFT(RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-FIND(".",A2)),FIND("@",RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-FIND(".",A2)))-1)))

Comment: Hey @BigBen, 

I've gotten this Formula 

=IFERROR(IF(FIND(".",A2)>FIND("@",A2),"",PROPER(LEFT(A2,FIND("@",A2)-1))),"")

to out put the first.last but I can't get it to output just the last name.

Comment: Use `MID` instead of `LEFT`.

Comment: I'm getting the error of too few arguments, and it highlights the -1 on the end of the formula. What should I be putting there?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean just replace LEFT with MID. You need to specify both the start position and the length with [MID](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/mid-midb-functions-d5f9e25c-d7d6-472e-b568-4ecb12433028).

Comment: Sorry,I don't meant to be a bother but the character length would change per the email that's typed in. I would need the Formula to just include everything after the first "." and before the First "@"

Comment: Right, so you can use the position of the `.` and the position of the `@` to figure out the length, using `FIND(".",A2)` and `FIND("@",A2)` as you are currently doing.

Comment: I'm sorry BigBen, but I still can't get the formula to work, I keep getting the there are too few arguments when i try using the Mid instead of Left

Comment: Try this: `=IFERROR(IF(FIND(".",A2)>FIND("@",A2),"",PROPER(MID(A2,FIND(".",A2)+1,FIND("@",A2)-1-FIND(".",A2)))),"")`

Answer (score 0):

Use an IF() and check if the position of the dot is before the @

```
=IF(FIND(".";A2)>FIND("@";A2);"";LEFT(A2;FIND(".";A2)-1))
```

Edit: OP appears to have the , as argument seperator instead of the ;

```
=IF(FIND(".",A2)>FIND("@",A2),"",LEFT(A2,FIND(".",A2)-1))
```

Comment: It say's there is an Error with this Formula

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way:

```
=IFERROR(IF(ISBLANK(A2),"",PROPER(LEFT(A2,MIN(FIND(".",A2), FIND("@",A2))-1))),"")
```

The above, returns whatever is  on the left of the first `.` or the `@`, which ever shows up first. The `IFERROR` is there to return a blank cell, should the entered have neither substrings